# Do you think this question is useful?

Tags: discussion

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116985/get-listt-values-in-late-binding-c-sharp) popped up in my review queue. It attracted quite a lot of answers but comments by the OP to these answers hints that the OP... perhaps does not have the required knowledge yet to understand any of them.

It is very tempting to vote to close. In fact, last time I checked it already had 4 close votes. But I feel that the question itself (if one improves the language) is not that bad. It's trivial for most intermediate programmers, but I understand how this can be a problem for a novice. As such, I think that answers to this question are quite useful. So I choose "Leave open" in the review options. Do you think this is justified, or is this question better be closed?

The reason I'm asking is to better understand how to handle similar situations in future.

**EDIT**: I edited the post in question, and although this was a major edit I hope, that it's for the better.

**EDIT2**: So now the question is closed despite the edit. I kind of understand this: it's really easy to add this last vote without really thinking: four people already voted for closure, they *must* be right =). Do you think this question worth re-opening?

Comment: I don't know what those people are answering. The question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @CodyGray That's a good point. I now see that it's really difficult to see what is being asked. But I *think* I understand the question. Now, yes, with such bad wording as this I can be wrong. And editing it to improve... yes it's going to be a major edit and there is no guarantee that my understanding is right. Looks like it's not such a great question after all. Still in the spirit of helping site visitors, is there anything that can be done but closure?

Comment: If you think you can salvage a poor quality question, then you should always edit it. The only other option is closing it. Editing is preferable if you really do see a legitimate question buried there, sometimes things click for one person when they don't for others.

Comment: @CodyGray, ok thanks. I edited it to the best of my abilities =)

Comment: That's a nice edit, @zespri. I looked at the question, and then Cody's first comment here confused me; it seemed like a perfectly lucid post.

Comment: zespri should get any positive reputation coming out of it (if any) because his question actually makes sense. The original version is simply horrible.

Comment: I think this question might be a case of beyond rescue.

Comment: With the latest edits, this is a good question with some good answers. It's too bad the OP can't understand them but I don't think that's a reason to close it.

Comment: Yeah, that is an impressive edit - I looked at the question as it is now, and it's a pretty good question. Then I looked at the original, and it was just shy of incomprehensibility. 
So yeah, it *would* be nice if zespri could get all the rep from upvotes on the question. :p
(I upvoted it - I've run into similar issues. Just ran into one like that just a couple days ago - went with the "make an interface" option.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the question can be useful to future viewers even if only novices can benefit from the question and/or answers, it should be left up.  If the question itself is bad and no reasonable amount of editing can save it, then vote to close it but otherwise if the question is at all redeemable you should comment asking for more details in order to improve it.