# Where did my edit go?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edits

I'm trying to help a new user clarify [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086655/implementation-of-server-client-model-need-some-advices) and get some helpful answers. I painstakingly crafted an edit and submitted it - successfully, as far as I could tell. It was sitting in the edit queue for a while (apparently there is such a thing; I can't actually see it).

I then wrote out and submitted an answer, only to discover that my supposedly pending edit was nowhere to be seen. What happened?

Comment: And as an aside, yes, that question is really frustrating to parse, but once you get past that, the OP did think through the problem from various angles. Certainly deserves some help.

Comment: Your suggested edit was [rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5445231); you can see this in your [suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/287610/lars-kemmann?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) tab. The three reviewers who rejected the edit gave the reason "This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost." Looking at the edit I'm inclined to agree: there's a lot that depends on interpretation of what the OP might have meant.

Comment: You might take an approach I used on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050916/not-adding-on-to-a-textbox/25055833#25055833) where I first summarize/interpret what *I think* the OP should have supplied in his question. And then answer the question.

Comment: Well, of course I'm going to disagree with the moderators on that point, @DavidRobinson, otherwise I wouldn't have taken the time to make the edit. :P But I certainly half-expected that that would happen.

Comment: Side-note: it *would* be nice if there were some indication, preferably with a link, when you submit an edit and it's rejected. I recall being confused myself, the first couple times that happened, and having to puzzle out where to find details about the edit rejections.

Comment: It's a bit of russian roulette. [I've done this before successfully](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260862/do-you-think-this-question-is-useful), but in my case the question was *closed* when I started with it, this helped to convince the community that a major edit is warranted. You had a very good intention but much less luck. Once you get past a certain number of rep points, this will stop being a problem.

Comment: And also people who review edits from the lower-rep users are not moderators (to address your comment above), just normal users, so it also contributes to the hit-or-miss situation

Comment: Good to know, thank you @zespri!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not visible to you after some time, because the user has rejected your edits. You can see your edit in pending queue with a message:

> Thanks for your edit!
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

In case the user rejected your suggested edits, it will disappear without any notification from the question.

Still, if you want to see your suggested edits, you can see it in your profile's suggested edits page, as [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267510/where-did-my-edit-go/267511#comment71334_267510) by **David Robson**.

Comment: You can find your suggested-edits in your profile as was pointed out by David Robson...

Comment: Thanks all. It was just buried a bit deeper than I expected. It would be nice if my suggested edits on a question were available *while viewing that question*. I suppose that's a feature request topic. :P

Comment: @LarsKemmann You might be interested to know that pending edits are shown to viewers who have edit review privileges.

Answer (score 22):

[Raj](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267511/1047207) posted a great answer on how you can find out *what* happened, since you're inclined to help users to the extent that you tried, I'd like to shed some light on the *why*.

You reached just a *little* too far in what you changed. In fact, you even made notes of this in your edit:

> [EDIT NOTE: Not sure what this means]

That's what *probably* caused your edit to be rejected as having too much scope, or possibly changing the intent of the post. As long as you're making *substantial* edits that (until you gain the privilege to edit without review) ensure reviews of your changes are time well-spent by reviewers, you don't need to document why you *didn't* change something; if it's that confusing, it will be obvious.

Make changes where you're sure, and [leave comments that encourage the OP to review them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267473/when-a-question-is-almost-a-good-question/267512#267512). Sometimes, well, the person most interested in the question needs to edit a bit too.

Your effort was spot on, and appreciated. As you advance your expertise in deciphering what most might call gibberish, you can make broader stabs at more substantial edits when you think you're *almost* certain. It really is a skill that you develop over time.

And, well, thanks for helping someone. That was nice of you :)

Completely aside and off-topic, I noticed you just hit 1,234 rep and I was compelled to preserve that:

[image: Because, well, 1,234]

Comment: Thanks Tim. That was nice of you. :)